# NavMenu foreach loop

Tags: foreach, blazor, blazor-webassembly

In my blazor app, I added the following code in `NavMenu.razor` :

```
@foreach (var item in surveys)
        {
             <div class="nav-item px-3">
                <NavLink class="nav-link" href="@($"survey/{item.Id}")" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
                    <span class="oi oi-star" aria-hidden="true"></span> @item.Title
                </NavLink>
            </div>
        }
```

And this is in the code section:

```
List<Survey> surveys = new List<Survey>();
    
    protected override async Task OnParametersSetAsync() {
        surveys = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Survey>>("https://localhost:5001/api/Surveys/");
    }
```

The problem is it won't change the component, although the url is changing properly. So I would get `https://localhost:4001/survey/2` and `https://localhost:4001/survey/1` when pressing the buttons, but the page stays the same.

Initially I had been using OnInitializedAsync, but I read that I should really be overriding OnParametersSetAsync and it didn't solve the problem.

Any idea on what should I change for the navigation to work?

This is the Survey class :

```
public class Survey
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string? Title { get; set; }
        public string? Description { get; set; }
        public string? Picture { get; set; }
    }
```

And the Surveys component that should render:

```
@page "/survey/{SurveyId:int}"
@inject HttpClient Http

@if(survey!=null){
    <div style="height: 100vh; background-image: url(@survey.Picture); background-size: cover;">
        <TopBar ComponentName=@survey.Title />
        This is survery @SurveyId - @survey.Id 
    </div>
}

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public int SurveyId { get; set; }

    private Survey survey;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync() {
        survey = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<Survey>("https://localhost:5001/api/Surveys/"+SurveyId);
    }

}
```

Comment: You are on the right path,  You are not changing the page component, so `OnInitializedAsync` only gets called the first time the component gets loaded.  You need to put your data retrieval code in `OnParametersSetAsync` and run it when the Id field changes.  If you need more help put the relevant bits of `Survey` in the question.

Comment: @MrCakaShaunCurtis 
 Thanks for answering! Do you mean I should check that in the survey component?

Comment: yes, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right path, You are not changing the page component, so OnInitializedAsync only gets called the first time the component gets loaded. You need to put your data retrieval code in OnParametersSetAsync and run it when the Id field changes.

Something like this:

```
@page "/survey/{SurveyId:int}"
<h3>Survey</h3>

@code {
    [Parameter] public int SurveyId { get; set; } = 0;

    private int currentId = 0;

    protected async override Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    {
        if (!this.SurveyId.Equals(this.currentId))
        {
            survey = await Http.GetFromJsonAsync<Survey>("https://localhost:5001/api/Surveys/" + SurveyId);
            this.currentId = this.SurveyId;
        }
    }
}
```

### Challenged Answer

As my answer to this question has been questioned, here's some simple code that demonstrates that `OnInitializedAsync` only gets called once in the scenario described in the question, and why you have to put your record loading code in `OnParametersSet{Async}`.

Section of NavMenu similar to the question:

```
        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
                <span class="oi oi-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Home
            </NavLink>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="/1" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
                <span class="oi oi-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Home 1
            </NavLink>
        </div>
        <div class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="/2" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
                <span class="oi oi-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Home 2
            </NavLink>
        </div>
```

Simple page with counters and ID to show we are using the same component (PageId) and the number of calls on each method.

```
@page "/"
@page "/{Id:int}"

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<SurveyPrompt Title="How is Blazor working for you?" />

<div class="p-2">
    Init: @Init
</div>
<div class="p-2">
    ParSet: @ParaSet
</div>
<div class="p-2">
    Page Id: @PageId
</div>
@code {
    [Parameter] public int Id { get; set; }

    private Guid PageId = Guid.NewGuid();

    private int Init = 0;

    private int ParaSet = 0;

    protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        Init++;
        return base.OnInitializedAsync();
    }

    protected override Task OnParametersSetAsync()
    {
        ParaSet++;
        return base.OnParametersSetAsync();
    }
}
```

Here's the result after a few clicks:

[image]

Comment: Please explain where? You know me, I have no problem in being proved wrong! ;-)  I've added some demo code to the answer to demonstrate the behaviour I've described.

Comment: When the user clicks on `survey/2` after `survey/1` in the scanario above, 'OnInitialized{async}' isn't called.  See my demo code  The route component doesn't change.  Only `OnParameters{Async}` gets called with the new parameter set.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I thouhjt that Blazor reuse the same component when one attempts to access it when the component is displayed. I mean that you change the url in the address bar from `/survey/1` to `/survey/2` .OK, I'll vote you up.

Comment: If you think through what the Renderer is doing, the behaviour, though unexpected, is logical.  It's only the router that understands the  "Page" concept. To the renderer it's just another component in the render tree.  The component hasn't changed, just one or more of the parameters,  You can also get caught out by thinking internal fields are set to initial values when they aren't!